# Unreal Engine 4 (UE4) Packaging Error - Unknown Error

Tags: packaging, unreal-engine4

I'm trying to package my project for Windows 64. The version I'm using is "Version: 4.16.1-3466753+++UE4+Release-4.16". It's my first time packaging a project, so I might be missing something fairly obvious.

This is the relevant part of the output log. https://pastebin.com/fSsY6dd8 or [UE4 Output Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uN5x1.png)

The last few lines are

```
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):    at AutomationTool.Program.Main()
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)): Program.Main: AutomationTool exiting with ExitCode=1 (Error_Unknown)
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)): BUILD FAILED
```

I'm setting the target folder to the C drive, which has c.80 GB free, so I don't see space being a problem. I've had a bit of a search about online, but nothing's proven helpful so far. The only thing I can think of is that my graphics aren't the best (I get a warning about it when I start the editor, but there's not much I can do as I'm using a university computer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted! Had an extra cpp file that I created accidently when not knowing what I was doing. Deleting that fixed it. See https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/776220/packaging-error-unknown-error-7.html